# object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python

object of type 'type' has no len()

this is my code:

```
 def search(li,n):
    l = 0
    u = len(li)-1
    while l <= u:
       mid = (l + u) //2
       if li(mid) == n:

          return True
       else :
            if li(mid) < n :
              l = mid
            else:
              u = mid
```

calling the function `search()`

here is the list:

```
li = [5,2,8,4,6,3,7,9]
n = 3

if search(list,n):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Comment: ``if search(list,n):`` should be ``if search(li,n):``

Answer (score 1):

The

```
if search(list,n):
```

should read

```
if search(li,n):
```

`list` is the name of a built-in type.

Separately, the correct way to index into a list is using square brackets, not parentheses.

Lastly, for the binary search algorithm to work, the list needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use square brackets to get an item of an list:

```
def search(li,n):
    l = 0
    u = len(li)-1
    while l <= u:
       mid = (l + u) //2
       if li[mid] == n:

          return True
       else :
            if li[mid] < n :
              l = mid
            else:
              u = mid

li = [5,2,8,4,6,3,7,9]
n = 3

if search(li,n):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a binary search on an unsorted list? Well, obviously, thats not gonna work. As for actually checking if a given value present in a list, in real life, in python, just use:

```
if n in li: 
    print("Found") 
else: 
    print("Not Found")
```